# Simple objective-c program doesn't work

Tags: objective-c

Does anyone know what is wrong with this code?

```
int squareOf = 1500;
int squarer = 1;

    for(int i = 0;i <= squareOf; i++){

        for(;squarer <= i; squarer++){

            if(i / squarer == 0){
                NSLog(@"%i",i);
            }
        }
```

It doesn't give me any errors, just it doesn't output anything. Anyone know why? Sorry if it's painfully obvious, I'm quite new to programming.

Comment: We'd have to see the variable definitions and how they're initialized to help you much.  (Though one can observe that squarer is unlikely to ever be larger than i, so the division will never produce 0.)

Comment: i/squarer is never equal to 0.

Comment: @HotLicks As he said: `int squareOf = 1500; int squarer = 1;`.

Comment: Really need more information. Is it an iOS app, OS X console app, or what? Did you check the console (command-shift-C)?

Comment: Why don't you single-step through your code in the debugger and check what happens? That should solve the problem quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if(i / squarer == 0)
```

It's never been called, put logs around the code and you'll understand:

```
for(int i = 0;i <= squareOf; i++){

        for(;squarer <= i; squarer++){
            NSLog(@"%d - %d", i, squarer)
            if(i / squarer == 0){
                NSLog(@"%i",i);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

During the first iteration the inner loop doesn't start, because `squarer` is 1, and `i` is 0, so the for condition is never met.

During the second iteration the inner loop is executed once, because `i` is 1 and also `squarer` is 1. `i/squarer` is 1 so it doesn't print anything.

During the third loop `squarer` is already 2 (incremented in the previous loop), `i` is 2 so the loop gets executed once, and `i/squarer` is again 1.

You can easily imagine what does happen in all the other loops: `i` is always equal to `squarer`, `i/squarer` is always 1. It is totally useless to use two nested loops for this purpose, see this code:

```
int squareOf = 1500;
int squarer = 1;
for(int i=1; i<=squareOf; i++) {
    if(i / squarer == 0)
        NSLog(@"%i",i);
    else
        NSLog(@"i/squarer is not zero");
}
```

It is the equivalent, `i/squarer` will never be zero, I added a log statement for clarity. Now you understand why `i/squarer` is always 1? If your intention was to write a different code, please tell me what you are trying to achieve, and I can try to correct the code.